# Symmetric Group Acting on homocyclic groups pt2

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-actions

This is an extension of my previous question on this topic. This time, we let $G=\underbrace{\mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z} \times \ldots \times \mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z}}_{n}$ and consider a subgroup of this $W \leq G$ such that for $W = \{(a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}) : a_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z}, \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n} = 0 \}$. We know that $\text{Sym
}(n)$ acts on on $G$ by permuting its factors. That is,

$$(a_{1},\ldots,a_{n})\sigma = (a_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,a_{\sigma(n)}).$$

Now notice that $\sum_{i}^{n}a_{i} = \sum_{i}^{n}a_{\sigma(i)} = 0$, so Sym$(n)$ will still act on $W$. But $W$can be expressed as:

$$\{(a_{1},\ldots,a_{n-1},-(a_{1} + a_{2} +\ldots + a_{n-1} ) ): a_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z}, \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n} = 0 \}$$

which i believe is isomorphic to

$$\{(a_{1},\ldots,a_{n-1}): a_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z} \}$$

so does this imply that, given that $\sigma$ can be viewed as a homomorphism and is bijective, that $\text{sym}(n) \leq \text{Aut}(\underbrace{\mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z} \times \ldots \times \mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z}}_{n-1})$

Comment: There must be some restrictions: consider the very small case  $n=2$, $k=1$, $p=2$.

Comment: And please can you tell us what $W$ is? It seems to be a set of $2n-2$-tuples.

Comment: @ancientmathematician So sorry made a silly mistake. Have now rectified this. Hope it makes more sense

Comment: What you get is an action of $Sym(n)$ on $W$, but if you want the embedding at the end, then you need to show that this action is faithful, which is often but not always the case. (Consider the parameters that ancientmathematician suggested, for example.)

Comment: By the way, I think it's a little easier to replace $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ by a generic abelian group $A$. It makes the notation easier, and also clearer what is needed to make this work.

Comment: What you call $W$ is often called the "augmentation submodule".

Comment: @verret What do you mean by embedding?

Comment: What you actually have is a homomorphism from $Sym(n)$ to $Aut(W)$. If this homomorphism is injective, then the image of $Sym(n)$ will actually be a subgroup of $Aut(W)$ isomorphic to $Sym(n)$.

Comment: I think it might help you understand if you look closely at the example ancientmathematician gave, with $n=2$ and $p^k=2$.
In this case, $W\cong C_2$, as you pointed out. But the automorphism group of $C_2$ is trivial, so $Aut(W)$ does not contain a subgroup isomorphic to $S_2$.

Comment: It IS true that the action of $S_2$ on $G$ gives a natural induced action of $S_2$ on $W$, it's just that in this case, the induced action is trivial!

Comment: On the other hand, I just did a quick check and I think in your setup this is the only exception. (This must be well known.)

Comment: @verret yes thinking about it that seems completely correct. I would guess there would be a restriction on $n \geq 3$. Thank you for help in me understanding this problem.

Comment: Even for $n=2$, I think the only exception in your case is when $p^k=2$. (More generally, for abelian groups, the only exception is when the exponent is $2$.) This is not that hard to see. When $n=2$, a typical element of $W$ looks like $(a,-a)$, and its image under the non-identity element of $S_2$ is $(-a,a)$. The only way this mapping can be trivial is if $a=-a$ for every element of the group.

Comment: It seems for me that for $n\geqslant 5$ the simplicity of $A_5$ will ensure that the homomorphism is injective. I haven't puzzled out the $n=4$ case when $p=2$; surely modular representation theory will help.

Comment: @verret would you be able to give me a tip on proving injectivity on this? (I'm only going to need to consider the $n \geq 3$ so we don't need to worry about that counter example).

Comment: See Derek's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $n>2$, then no permutation mapping $1$ to $2$ fixes $(1,0,\ldots,0,-1)$, but there's nothing special about $1$ and $2$, so no non-identity permutation acts trivially on $W$.

If $n=2$, then $(1,2)$ maps $(1,-1)$ to $(-1,1)$, so the action is nontrivial except when $p^k=2$.

Comment: Sorry, I dont quite understand the first point. Why does it matter that we have some permutation that doesn't fix a certain element of $\mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z} \times \ldots \times \mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z}$? I understand that, given this is true, then your conclusion holds. I just don't quite understand the first part.

Comment: In your question, you point out that $Sym(n)$ has an action on $W$. We want to know if this action is faithful. (If you don't know what that means, you should look it up first.) This is the same as asking whether any non-identity element of $Sym(n)$ acts trivially on $W$ (or, in other words, fixes every element of $W$.) So Derek takes a generic non-identity element of $Sym(n)$, and shows that it must move some element of $W$.